# r - renamefrom function from crosswalkr returning 0 columns

Tags: r, rename

I am having issues with the `renamefrom` function from the `crosswalkr` package. when I run anything different than what is in the documentation, I do not get any columns.

```
library(crosswalkr)


# documentation example
df <- data.frame(state = c('Kentucky','Tennessee','Virginia'),
                 fips = c(21,47,51),
                 region = c('South','South','South'))

cw <- data.frame(old_name = c('state','fips'),
                 new_name = c('stname','stfips'),
                 label = c('Full state name', 'FIPS code'))


df1 <- renamefrom(df, cw, old_name, new_name)


# when i have a different table
df <- data.frame(Item_ID = c(101163, 101165, 101167),
                 Type = c("Apple", "Pizza", "Drink"))

cw <- data.frame(old_name = c("Item_ID", "Type"),
                 new_name = c("New_ID", "Product"))

df1 <- renamefrom(df, cw, old_name, new_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was connected with the upper case characters in the `df` column names and was fixed in [the v0.2.4 release](https://github.com/btskinner/crosswalkr/releases/tag/v0.2.4) of the `crosswalkr` package. (Thanks to the author @Benjamin Skinner for the prompt response!)

The temporary solution for older version of the package is to set `case_ignore = FALSE`:

```
df2 <- renamefrom(df, cw, old_name, new_name,
    case_ignore = FALSE, drop_extra = FALSE)
```

or

```
df3 <- renamefrom(df, cw, old_name, new_name,
    case_ignore = FALSE, drop_extra = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the case functionality is not working correctly and it either needs to be lower case headers, or `case_ignore = F`.

Comment: Your `df2` basically just gives the same dataframe even though my cases do match. `df3` works but could cause you to lose information if you don't have a column name. You should add `df4 <- renamefrom(df, cw, old_name, new_name, case_ignore = F, drop_extra = F)`

Comment: @alexb523 You are absolutely right. It seems that `case_ignore = T` combined with `drop_extra = F` is not a very helpful solution. I have updated the answer replacing df2 with the option which you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a bug, but should be fixed with the updated version (0.2.4) on GitHub.

```r
library(crosswalkr)

## setup data/crosswalk
df <- data.frame(Item_ID = c(101163, 101165, 101167),
                 Type = c("Apple", "Pizza", "Drink"))

cw <- data.frame(old_name = c("Item_ID", "Type"),
                 new_name = c("New_ID", "Product"))

## call command
df1 <- renamefrom(df, cw, old_name, new_name)

## old
df
#>   Item_ID  Type
#> 1  101163 Apple
#> 2  101165 Pizza
#> 3  101167 Drink

## new
df1
#>   New_ID Product
#> 1 101163   Apple
#> 2 101165   Pizza
#> 3 101167   Drink
```